# How to replace a native dynamic library file permanently and appropriately

Tags: linux, odbc, shared-libraries, unixodbc, dynamic-library

I try to develop a thirdparty unixODBC driver, it is a secondary development based on the original file libodbc.so.2.0.0.

so I want to rename 'libodbc.so.2.0.0' to 'libodbc.so.2.0.0_renamed'. And soft link my dynamic library file to libodbc.so.2.0.0.

But I found an issue bothering me, when I rename native file and run 'sudo ldconfig', the file named 'libodbc.so.2' automatically linked to the renamed file 'libodbc.so.2.0.0_renamed', as below:
[image: shell figure]

I could not understand that:

- why it occurs;
- how to appropriately replace the library.

I don't have enough ackownledge about linux, so that I failed to get any keyword to search and deal with it.

Could you help me, thank you very much!

Comment: According to the naming convention, your rename operation changes the version number of the library but keeps the library name. I suggest to rename the file to e.g. `libodbc_renamed.so.2.0.0`.

Comment: @Bodo Thanks. In fact, the 'libodbc_renamed.so.2.0.0' is used in my env, but it still don't work. the name as 'libodbc.so.2.0.0_renamed' is good for me doing 'ls libodbc.*'.

Answer (score 0):

Shared objects under GNU/Linux follow a specific version naming scheme, which is known by the loader (and OS component, actually part of libc framework) to determine if a newer library is retro-compatible with some older version to which a binary was originally linked against. By adding the `renamed` suffix, you are violating the convention and the dynamic linking system is getting confused.  You should renamed as suggested by @Bodo above.

In addition, perhaps rather than using `rename`, you might consider using the very versioning scheme. From GNU Build System (aka Autotools) manual, the version cheme is like it follows:

```
Versioning: CURRENT:REVISION:AGE                                               
CURRENT The latest interface implemented.                                      
REVISION The implementation number of CURRENT (read: number of bugs fixed...)  
AGE The number of interfaces implemented, minus one.                           
The library supports all interfaces between CURRENT − AGE and CURRENT.         
                                                                                
If you have                                                                    
not changed the interface (bug fixes)         CURRENT : REVISION+1 : AGE       
augmented the interface (new functions)       CURRENT+1 : 0 : AGE+1            
broken old interface (e.g. removed functions) CURRENT+1 : 0 : 0
```

Therefore a possible history of your lib might be:

```
1:0:0   start
1:1:0   bug fix
1:2:0   bug fix
2:0:1   new function
2:1:1   bug fix
2:2:1   bug fix
3:0:0   broke api
3:1:0   bug fix
4:1:1   bug fix
5:0:0   broke api
```

You might, for instance, call the older and newer versions of libodbc.so.x.y.z, according to your needs. Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks! I will attempt as your recommondation then.